# /bin/bash printf does not work with other LANG than C

Tags: bash, locale, printf, zsh

I have a really weird problem with /bin/bash and a script that uses printf to format a string.

My script looks like this

```
rt=$(printf "%.3f" 13.234324245)
```

with the difference, that i compute the number 13.23... above. When i use /usr/bin/zsh that works great! Even /bin/sh can do it (but it cant do the if stuff...)
The biggest problem ist that /bin/bash seems to does not understand printf or does have another formating way when i dont use `LANG=C`.

My LANG Variable is set to `de_AT.UTF-8` and then i get this Error:

```
/path/to/script: Zeile 12: printf: 13.234324245: Ungültige Zahl.
```

So it simply says that the number i gave printf is invalid...

Do i need to run printf in a different way?

edit: The problem seems to be on the computation of the number:

```
rt=$(printf "%.3f" $(echo "$res2 - $res1"|bc ))
```

how i can tell bc to use a `,` instead of `.`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem stems for the `LC_NUMERIC` setting, which bash follows when parsing arguments to `printf`.

I find this behavior dubious. Ksh93 also parses numbers according to `LC_NUMERIC` while pdksh and dash want a dot as the separator in the argument, and zsh accepts either a dot or the local format. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html) doesn't say, because the floating point format specified are optional in `printf` (`LC_NUMERIC` must be respected when printing numbers though).

As a user I recommend never setting `LC_NUMERIC` and `LC_COLLATE` except in very specific circumstances where you're sure you want their behavior. This means not using `LANG` and setting specific categories instead; most people only need `LC_CTYPE` (character encoding), `LC_MESSAGES` (language of messages) and `LC_TIME` (date and time format). In a script, you can override all categories by setting `LC_ALL`, or a specific category by setting it (setting `LANG` only overrides `$LANG` and not a user-set `$LC_NUMERIC`).

```
#!/bin/sh
LC_NUMERIC=C LC_COLLATE=C
printf "%.3f" 13.234324245
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do a `$(LANG=C printf "%.3f" 13.234324245)`, just set `LANG` on this command

Comment: I recommend setting `LC_NUMERIC` rather than `LANG`, to also override a user-set `LC_NUMERIC`. Or even `LC_ALL` which trumps them all.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a locale issue - I think that in German the decimal separator is comma `,` rather than period `.`. Try using `13,234324245` as your value.

Comment: but then, how do i do that when the float is comming out of bc? sed it? D:

Comment: Probably the easiest thing in this instance is to use @J-16's solution and force LANG=C.

Answer (score 2):

You can use other `printf` implementations: with non-builtin /usr/bin/printf:

```
% # LANG is ru_RU.UTF8, decimal separator is comma
% /usr/bin/printf %.3f 3.14
3,140
% /usr/bin/printf %.3f 3,14
/usr/bin/printf: 3,14: значение преобразовано не полностью
3,000
% LANG=C /usr/bin/printf %.3f 3,14
printf: 3,14: value not completely converted
3.00
```

With `zsh` built-in printf implementation:

```
% printf %.3f 3.14
3,140
% printf %.3f 3,14
3,140
```