# Bash round 2 decimal places with dot

Tags: linux, bash, printf, decimal

I used printf "%0.2f\n" $myVar method to display something on 2 decimal places, but it doesnt work for numbers with dot (.) as decimal mark, but comma(,)

Anybody has any idea what should i do?

http://puu.sh/owM1p/21f5be08c2.jpg

Comment: This looks like an issue of confusion with your [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale) settings. Please look at or show the output of the `locale` command.  You can change the locale used for specific things (like `LC_NUMERIC`) by changing the appropriate values of variables. (I'd try `C` or `POSIX` locale.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting your locale environment variable LC_NUMERIC to some locale that uses period. E.g.

```
LC_NUMERIC="C" printf "%0.2f\n" 3.1415
```

The locale needs to be installed in your system. To get full list of the locales installed, use `locale -a`

Comment: The OP is in a locale that uses comma, that's why it isn't working for numbers containing `.` as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM WAS LOCALE as someone pointed out
I didnt know what caused error and i thank you.

more on this link
[/bin/bash printf does not work with other LANG than C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848335/bin-bash-printf-does-not-work-with-other-lang-than-c)